# Pandas timeseries with superimposed lines

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames in pandas one with four timesseries with second by second data like the following

```
timestamp            ID     value1 value2 value3 value4
2016/01/01T01:01:01  1234      100   50      50    60
2016/01/01T01:01:02  1234      101   48      48    52
2016/01/01T01:01:02  1234      101   48      48    52
....
```

and a second with averages from selected intervals

```
ID start_time    end_time  avg_value1 avg_value2 avg_value3 avg_value4
1234 01:01:01      01:01:15     100.1    50.2        49          55
...
```

I would like to plot these two as timeseries superimposed over each other with the averages appearing as flat lines starting at start_time and ending at end_time. How would I go about doing this in the latest version of pandas?

Comment: Start here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to put all the data into a single DataFrame and use the built-in `.plot()` method.

Assuming your original DataFrame is called `df` the the code below should solve your issue (you might need to strip out the "ID" column):

```
means = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('15s')).mean()
means.columns = ['avg_'+col for col in df.columns]
merged_df = pd.concat([df, means], axis=1).fillna(method='ffill')
merged_df.plot()
```

Using some intraday 1s candle stock data, you get something like this:

[image]

If you want to further customize your plots I am afraid you will have to spend a few hours/days studying the basics of matplotlib.